Optimal Martingale Type p Constant of Hilbert Spaces
Definition
A Banach space $(X, || \cdot ||)$ is said to have martingale type $p\in[1,2]$ if there exists a constant $C_{p,X}$ such that every $X$-valued Martingale Difference Sequence $\left(D_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ satisfies
$$
E\left[\left\Vert \sum_{n=1}^N D_n \right\Vert^p\right]^{\frac 1 p} \leq C_{p,X} \left(\sum_{n=1}^N \mathbb E\left[ \left\Vert D_n \right \Vert^p\right]\right)^{\frac 1 p}
$$
for all $N \in \mathbb N$, see e.g. [1, Section 3.5.d].
Question
What is the optimal constant $C_{p,\mathcal H}$ for $p \in [1,2]$ and a Hilbert Space $\mathcal H$?
Attempts
It is likely that I am missing something obvious: The triangle inequality implies $C_{1, \mathcal H} = 1$ and orthogonality implies $C_{2, \mathcal H} = 1$.
In particular it would be intuitive to believe that $C_{p, \mathcal H}=1$ for all $p \in [1,2]$.
However the best constant I can derive is $p^* - 1$, where $p^* = \max\left\{p , \frac{p}{p-1}\right\}$, which is clearly sub-optimal:

By [1, section 4.5.d] the optimal unconditional martingale differences (UMD) property constant for Hilbert spaces is $\beta_{p, \mathcal H} = p^* - 1$.
Hilbert spaces have Rademacher type $p$ with constant $\tau_{p, \mathcal H} = 1$, see e.g. [2]. Hence:

$$
E\left[\left\Vert \sum_{n=1}^N D_n \right\Vert^p\right]
\leq \beta_{p, \mathcal H}^p 
E\left[\left\Vert \sum_{n=1}^N \varepsilon_n D_n \right\Vert^p\right]
\leq \beta_{p, \mathcal H}^p \tau_{p, \mathcal H} \sum_{n=1}^N 
\mathbb E\left[ \left\Vert D_n \right\Vert^p\right],
$$
where $\varepsilon_1, \dots, \varepsilon_N$ are Rademacher and independent of each other and $D_1, \dots, D_N$. In particular $\beta_{p, \mathcal H}$ is a (clearly sub-optimal) bound on the optimal $C_{p, \mathcal H}$.

[1] Hytönen, T., Van Neerven, J., Veraar, M. and Weis, L., 2016. Analysis in Banach spaces (Volume 1). Berlin: Springer.
[2] Haagerup, U., 1981. The best constants in the Khintchine inequality. Studia Mathematica, 70(3), pp.231-283.

Not sure if it helps but perhaps you can get a better constant by looking at the proof of the theorem which states that if a space has MG type $p$ then it has MG type $r$ for all $1 \le r \le p$.

Thank you for your comment @EvangelopoulosFoivos! The proof of this Theorem I found is [1, Proposition 3.5.27], which sadly only mentions that $C_{r, \mathcal H} \simeq_{r,p} C_{p, \mathcal H}$ for $r \in [1,p]$. Are you by any chance familiar with other works that potentially derive this constant (more) explicitly?

Ah... I see. I am not aware of any other references at the moment. This is an interesting question!

In Theorem 2 of the paper
Cox DC. Note on a martingale inequality of Pisier. Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society. 1982;92(1):163-165. doi:10.1017/S0305004100059818
it is shown that
$$
C_{p,X}^p=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R,x\neq 0}\frac{\lvert 1+x\rvert^p-px-1}{\lvert x\rvert^p}
$$
is the optimal constant in the wanted inequality.
See also
Iosif Pinelis. "Best possible bounds of the von Bahr--Esseen type." Ann. Funct. Anal. 6 (4) 1 - 29, 2015. https://doi.org/10.15352/afa/06-4-1
for further references on the topic.

Many thanks for the concise answer and references! I have accepted your answer and have a short follow-up question. The cited work considers the setting $p \in (1,2]$ and, for $p\searrow1$, the given constant converges to $C_{p, \mathcal H} \to 2$. By the triangle inequality, the optimal constant for $p=1$ is $C_{1, \mathcal H} = 1$. Is there some intuition for this discontinuity?
